# The negation of $ A(t)\subseteq B(t)$ $\mu-a.e$

Tags: measure-theory, logic, banach-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be probability space and $X$ be a separable Banach space. the associated dual space is denoted by $X^*$ and the usual duality between $X$ and $X^*$ by $\langle.,.\rangle$. Let $H$ be  a countable, dense subset in $X^*$ for weak$-*$ topology

*we suppose, we have a problem, as* :

Show that there exists a nul set $M\in\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$
A(t)\subseteq B(t)\qquad \forall t\in E\smallsetminus M.\qquad(∗)
$$

with, for $t\in E$ : we pose  $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ two subset of $X$ such that there exists two  function $f_A,f_B:E\times X^*\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
A(t)=\bigcap_{x^*\in H}\{x\in X:\langle x^*,x\rangle\leq f_A(t,x^*) \}
$$
$$
B(t)=\bigcap_{x^*\in H}\{x\in X:\langle x^*,x\rangle\leq f_B(t,x^*) \}
$$
**Problem**:

The negation of $(*)$ is : there exists a non nul set $N\in\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$
A(t)\nsubseteq B(t)\qquad \forall t\in N.
$$
then
$$
\forall t\in N,\exists x^*_t\in H\text{ such that : }f_A(t,x^*)>f_B(t,x^*) 
$$
Can we say that : Since $H$ is countable, then there exist $x^*\in  H$ and a nonnull set $N^{'}$ such that
$$
f_A(t,x^*)>f_B(t,x^*) \qquad\forall t\in N^{'}
$$

Comment: As I said on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363747/the-negation-of-at-subseteq-bt-mu-a-e#comment917700_363747), your negation is not correct, so it's useless to consider the measure theory yet.  To find the correct negation, it may help to write it as a sentence in predicate logic, ignoring the measure-theoretic details, and negate it symbolically.

Comment: I did not understand your comment. If we assume that $(*)$ is not true, then what do we have?